# How to configure ActiveRecord default open connection with database and how to verify it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

We would like to get your help with regards to the following- (a) In RoR Active Records, how to specify or control the number of database (DB) connections to be open by default? (b) How to monitor and verify what number of actual connections have been established between Active Records and database? (c) Does it depend on the actual database server- like is it going to be different for Postgres and AWS Aurora?

Comment: You can monitor connections using https://github.com/ankane/pghero . I believe you can limit connections in your config/database.yml

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pool` key in your `config/database.yml` file.

To monitor connections take a look at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/ConnectionPool.html

It has `stat` method, that returns some pool usage related data.